# Rails: On tab click submit a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that I would like to be submitted when you click the tab button on your keyboard. I think I'm doing with my own code... How will I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myElement.keydown = function (e) {
  if (e.which === 9) myForm.submit();
};
```

`9` is the tab character. I think this is x-browser compatible.

Comment: myForm is the name of the form? And myElement is what?

Comment: You could also use "document.body" instead of "myElement".

Comment: myElement is the element you want to want to bind the event to, you may or may not want to bind it to document (the entire page), you could bind it to just an input element by fetching it, such as `document.forms.myFormId.elements.myElementId.keydown = ...`. `myForm` is the form element, such as `document.forms.myFormId`